# wildcard search on triples in MarkLogic

Tags: sparql, marklogic

Is it possible to perform wildcard search on triples using `cts` query?

I have tried in `sparql`, I am getting the right results but the query is very slow.

for example:

```
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
select ?iri
where {
   ?iri skos:prefLabel ?prefLabel .
   filter (STRSTARTS(lcase(?prefLabel), 'soviet'))
} limit 250
```

Above query is returning me the right results but the query is extremely slow.

As I am building a auto suggestion API and it is supposed to be extremely fast.

Please help.

**Update after daves comment:**

I have tried the second approach and it is better than the previous one but not that much fast.
`cts filtered` query is running bit slow, We can't do `unfiltered` search on the current xml structure.

In the project we need the suggestions to be very fast so to do this I have tried the below approach.

I have created XML files as described below for each subject

```
<record>
    <pref-label>Dixit Singla</pref-label>
    <iri>prefix:12345</iri>
</record>
```

Now using `cts:element-values on iri element` and filtering it with `wildcarded cts:element-value-query on pref-label` I am getting all the matched iris and passing them to sparql query. By this I can see a great performance improvement.

```
cts:element-values(xs:QName('iri'), (),(), cts:element-value-query(xs:QName('pref-label'), 'sov* *'))
```

I know that above approach will consume more memory but that's fine as the performance is really good :)

Observation: when subjects are passed in `sparql` it runs very fast.

like:

```
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
select ?iri
where {
   values ?iri {prefix:12345 prefix:12346 prefix:12339 prefix:12345}
   ?iri skos:prefLabel ?prefLabel .
   #apply filters
} limit 250
```

Comment: without a fulltext index you're mostly lost in SPARQL as a full scan + filter on the intermediate result has to be done. does Marklogic support fulltext search features? if so, just use it

Comment: ok, `cts:contains` works natively in SPARQL. You can try if  `cts:search` is also possible and use the XQuery expression then. I don't have a Marklogic server here

Comment: XPath via `fn:` prefix is also possible, but if no fulltext index is used here, checking for string start will still be expensive

Comment: Are you using managed or embedded triples?

Comment: Managed triples.

Answer (score 3):

Two approaches listed in this answer

---

Try this:

```
sem:sparql(
  "PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
   select ?iri
   where {
      ?iri skos:prefLabel ?prefLabel .
      filter (STRSTARTS(lcase(?prefLabel), 'soviet'))
   } limit 250",
  (),
  (),
  sem:store("any", cts:element-query(xs:QName("sem:object"), cts:word-query("soviet*")))
)
```

`sem:store` identifies a set of triples. By passing in the word-query, we're finding just those triples that occur in documents that contain a `<sem:object>` that starts with "soviet".

Even managed triples show up as either XML or JSON in documents. When you insert managed triples, MarkLogic decides how to divide them up into files. If you have a lot of triples, this approach should cut down the number that the SPARQL query is running against.

---

edits based on @grtjn's comments:

- yes, that should have been "soviet*" -- fixed
- as noted this approach works because the SPARQL query is very simple -- it's only looking for triples that have a particular object pattern. This would not work if the SPARQL query needed to connect to other triples, because those triples may well have been excluded by the `sem:store` call.

---

Second approach. The goal is to do a wildcard search on objects, then get the subject IRIs and pass those to a SPARQL query.

Since these are managed triples, we know that they will be in XML documents with a root of `sem:triples` and each triple will be represented like this:

`<sem:triple>
  <sem:subject>http://example.com/my-subject</sem:subject>
  <sem:predicate>http://example.com/my-predicate</sem:predicate>
  <sem:object datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">my-object</sem:object>
</sem:triple>`

We can create a wildcard query that targets the object strings:

```
cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("sem:object"), "soviet *", "wildcarded")
```

Note the space between "soviet" and "*". The docs for [`cts:element-value-query`](http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:element-value-query) explain why:

> Note that the text content for the value in a cts:element-value-query is treated the same as a phrase in a cts:word-query, where the phrase is the element value. Therefore, any wildcard and/or stemming rules are treated like a phrase. For example, if you have an element value of "hello friend" with wildcarding enabled for a query, a cts:element-value-query for "he*" will not match because the wildcard matches do not span word boundaries, but a cts:element-value-query for "hello *" will match. A search for "*" will match, because a "*" wildcard by itself is defined to match the value. Similarly, stemming rules are applied to each term, so a search for "hello friends" would match when stemming is enabled for the query because "friends" matches "friend".

You might want to use `cts:element-word-query` instead.

We can then use the `$expression` parameter on `cts:search` to make sure we only get the triples we want. Note that this requires filtering. Once we have the triples, we can use XPath to get the subjects, then pass them to a SPARQL query.

Putting that all together, we get:

```
let $query := cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("sem:object"), "soviet *")
let $subjects := cts:search(/sem:triples/sem:triple, $query)/sem:subject/fn:string()
```

Pass your `$subjects` into your SPARQL query and off you go. This should work; the question I'm left with is whether it's any faster than what you started with. I'd be interested to hear the results of your testing.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `"soviet*"`?

Comment: A sem:store with a cts:query can trim down the triples evaluated by the sparql engine upfront considerable, providing massive performance improvements, but be careful not to exclude triples you might need. There are no guarantees about which triples are persisted where with triples 'managed' by MarkLogic..

Comment: @dave Thanks for your reply, but I can not use 'store' as I have to connect to other triples as well(as you have already mentioned) and I have to filter the triples on some other predicates as well in sparql. Is there ant other way like making use of `cts:search wildcarded` capabilities to get the subject IRIs and pass those iris in sparql query.

Comment: @DixitSingla please see second approach above

Comment: @DaveCassel I have tried the second approach. Please have a look at the 'Update after daves comment' section.